# Making the amount of strings checked change based on the amount of strings in a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Title was really bad, didn't know how to put it.

Essentially i need to check if a input from a txt file is in lexicographical order. i read from the file, load the individual words into a list and then check using python's ' < ' if it is true.

The part i need help with is doing

word1 < word2 < word3

the right amount of times for however many words are in the list and for however many lines are in the file.
so if line 1 was only 2 words long it would only do

word1 < word2

but it line 1 was 5 words long it would check

word1 < word2 < word3 < word4 < word5

My code is allll over the place at the moment because i am honestly stumped, i'm relatively new to python so explanations would help

```
with open ("lines.txt", "r") as myfile:
   linelist = myfile.readlines()
   count = len(linelist)
   l1 = linelist[0]
   line1split = l1.split()
   l1count = len(line1split)
   l2 = linelist[1]
   line2split = l2.split()
   l2count = len(line2split)
   l3 = linelist[2]
   line3split = l3.split()
   l3count = len(line3split)
   l4 = linelist[3]
   line4split = l4.split() 
   l4count = len(line4split) 
   l5 = linelist[4]
   line5split = l5.split()
   l5count = len(line5split) 
   line1split = l1.split()

     if line1split[0] < line1split[1]: 
       print('Line 1 is ascending.')
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: I think you need to first check all word available in line then check it within loop.

Comment: If word1<word2 then i just need to print 'line 1 is ascending'

Comment: only if `word1 < word2` ? What is word3 is less than word2 ?

Comment: @NickAdams so you mean there are only two words in line1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use nested for loops , first for loop to iterate over the line, and the second for loop to iterate over each word in the line. Example -

```
with open ("lines.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(myfile):
        flag = True
        words = line.split()
        for j, word in enumerate(words):
            if j == len(words) - 1:
                break
            elif word >= words[j+1]:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            print('Line {} is ascending'.format(i+1))
```

Comment: My list looks like this .... Once upon a time\n
there was\n
a boy named tom\n
who liked cheese\n
and crackers\n   but it just returns ' line 2 is ascending, line 4 is ascending and line 2 is ascending again' doesnt seem to work

Comment: No, the \n represent where the breaks in the lines are

Comment: The first edit on the comment didn't have `\n` , anyway, for this first line is not ascending right? Thats what you want as output right?

Comment: For the above lines it should output, Line 2 is ascending.
Line 3 is ascending.
Line 5 is ascending.